# как запретить редирект с некоторых страниц или целой папки?

Tags: .htaccess

В `htaccess` присутствует простой редирект на `index.php`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Но дело в том что есть `ajax` запрос который не может выполниться из-за редиректа

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../function/signup.php",
        data: "name="+name,
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 'yes'){
                alert('yes');
            }else{
                alert(data);    
            }
        }
  });
```

Как запретить редирект если url идет обращение в папку например `function`

Нашел такой вариант, но прописывать так каждый `url` не вариант, может можно сделать так что бы запрет на ридеркт был если в `url` присутствует `function`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/function/signup_user\.php$
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
# исключение для всех файлов php из папки function и ее подпапок
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/function/.+\.php$
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, сейчас попробую